# Recognize js files in the library folder

Tags: 7

If i put my .js files in sites->all->libraries folder. Will drupal recognize it ? Because i did not see the file in the source. Can i make it recognize ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just putting the files in a directory won't do any good.

You have to either put a reference to your file in your module.info file, or use [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) somewhere, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `sites/all/libraries/` exists so that modules can know where you've put various non-Drupal code libraries. There's a [Libraries module](http://drupal.org/project/libraries), and contrib modules can declare it a dependency so that you know you're supposed to use an external library in there. Basically: Don't put anything there unless you're installing a module that tells you to do so. Countzero's answer is correct about how to add JS to your site.